# How to make a smiley face in Turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, turtle-graphics

First time ever using Turtle. My assignment is to make a smiley face, any size and any position. I just can't get the mouth right because I really don't know what I'm doing. I've read quite a bit and what I want to do is after the right smile, start and (0,0) and just make a mirror image of it. Thanks for any help.

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
smiles = turtle.Turtle()

smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(-75,150)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(10)     #eye one

smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(75,150)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(10)     #eye two

smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(0,0)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(100,90)   #right smile

smiles.penup()            #below is where i feel i'm messing up
smiles.goto(0,0)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(-100,90)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could call `setheading(180)` to make the turtle look West:

```
import turtle

smiles = turtle.Turtle()    
smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(-75,150)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(10)     #eye one

smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(75,150)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(10)     #eye two

smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(0,0)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(100,90)   #right smile

smiles.penup()           
smiles.setheading(180) # <-- look West
smiles.goto(0,0)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(-100,90)
```

[image: smile drawn by turtle]

You could try it online e.g. http://www.skulpt.org

Answer (score 1):

def smileyface():
    penup()
    goto(-75,150)
    pendown()
    circle(10)

```
penup()
goto(75,150)
pendown()
circle(10)     

penup()
goto(0,0)
pendown()
circle(100,90)   

penup()            
goto(0,0)
pendown()
circle(-100,90)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turtle keeps track of its orientation when it does a partial circle.  Insert this line:

```
smiles.penup()            #below is where i feel i'm messing up
smiles.circle(0, 270)     # New line here
smiles.goto(0,0)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(-100,90)
```

to spin it around to start a new circle.